# Generate an aleatoire combination of decimal making sure not generate a duplicate of this combination

Tags: c#, algorithm, probability

I wrote the following method to help me to generate a combination of decimal digits in C# :

```
public static string GenerateCodeNumeric(int length)
{
        Random random = new Random();
        string characters = "0123456789";
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(length);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            result.Append(characters[random.Next(characters.Length)]);
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
```

The issue here is there is a probability that this method produce two or more identical combination, is there any idea to prevent this of happening?

I have a proposition to solve this :

1. every time that my method generates a code, I will stock it in a table in the database, and before generating this code I look over in this table if that code already exist.

But the problem here is when my table will be heavy of data it will take a long time to look over if this code already exit ... and it will reduce the performance...

Comment: have you google around?

Comment: @Steve no ... I am stackoverflowing it here :p

Comment: well you should. You will only receive down votes if you come to SO without search effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It it were for me, I would just increment a counter, that's an absolute guarantee of no collision. (And if you need to generate the codes at different places, reserve some fixed digits to distinguish between them.)

Then if you need the codes to look random, scramble the bits in a reversible way so that distinct values remain distinct. If the codes are long enough, you can even insert random extra bits where you like.

By such a procedure, the values are implicitly unique and there is no need to check after the fact.